# Surpassing 70%c of spinning black holes - projection

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, speed-of-light, astrophysics

[And in some cases, the holes are spinning at an extremely rapid pace. The hole in one quasar, Einstein Cross, was spinning about as fast as theoretically possible -- 70 percent the speed of light](https://www.engadget.com/2019-07-07-spinning-black-holes-nasa.html)

In my view of this limitation, if the holes spin faster than 70%c, they become a diametrical motor, like a pair of scissors spitting everything out.

Or is it wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The quote in the OP is not exactly right. I guess this is the typical case where a scientific report is misinterpreted and reposted in a news article.

The source of the article you quote is [this report by NASA](https://www.engadget.com/2019-07-07-spinning-black-holes-nasa.html?guccounter=1), which in turn refers to [this paper in the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.06007).

Quoting the NASA report:

> The matter in one of these cosmic vortices is swirling around its black hole at greater than about 70% of the speed of light.

and after a few paragraphs:

> The results showed that one of the black holes, in the lensed quasar called the “Einstein Cross,” is spinning at, or almost at, the maximum rate possible. This corresponds to the event horizon, the black hole’s point of no return, spinning at the speed of light, which is about 670 million miles per hour. Four other black holes in the sample are spinning, on average, at about half this maximum rate.

So it is not the black hole that is spinning at 70% of the speed of light, but the material that is swirling around it.
You can imagine the black hole as a large dark sphere surrounded by a disk of material, similar to Saturn's, but the disk is spinning extremely fast. The authors of the papers were able to measure the size of the inner radius of the disk, that is, the distance between the black hole and the closest orbiting particles.

This measure can give an indication of the speed of the material swirling around the black hole, because the closer you are to the black hole, the faster you have to move to stay in orbit. And this is where the 70% figure comes from.

Additionally, this also tells you how fast the black hole itself is spinning, because general relativity predicts a clear relation between the spin of a black hole and the minimum radius that a stable circular orbit can have. The faster the black hole is spinning, the smallest is this minimum radius.

But there is a limit to how fast a black hole can spin. For a black hole really close to the limit, the minimum radius of a stable orbit approaches the event horizon, and the particles in orbit approach the speed of light.

If a black hole had a spin greater than the limit, some equations of general relativity would give very weird results: the black hole would cease to have an event horizon and would become a [naked singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_singularity). We have never observed anything like that and have [good reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_censorship_hypothesis) to believe that this is not something that exists.

The image of a ball that is spinning so fast that it spits everything out is thus not correct for a black hole. It is difficult to predict how a naked singularity would behave, but it would probably not spit everything that fell into it before.

On the contrary, this is a good analogy for a fast rotating neutron star. Neutron stars have a maximum spin limit after which the star would not be able to keep itself together. Yet, usually this does not happen in nature, because the mechanisms that use to spin up the neutron stars become ineffective when the star approaches the limit.